# How to render large 1gb+ csv as a html table

Tags: javascript, python, php, html

I have a large csv file which basically is a correlation matrix across thousands of tickers. I have attached a screenshot of it

[image]
I want to render it as a HTML table, whats the most easiest and efficient way to do this. I have tried using papaparse as has been suggested on the web but the page fails to load but works for smaller csv files

Comment: You want to display 1Gb of data in a web page?  Please reconsider, this does not make any sense...  Anything you put in a web page has to be downloaded.  Even if you use Ajax to download it in parts, you will still have to download the content eventually.  Anyway when it gets that big, no user is going to view the page.  And if it is too heavy, users will hit timeout values before they get it all.

Comment: You can explode the CSV data and then use foreach() or while() to get better control of what you want to display, but as @nic3500 says, everytime you will reload the page you will going to download 1Gb of data... so why not use a database? or if you use while() you may specify which array index you want to see, but your server will be working a lot trying to look for the specific index... theres a better ways to achieve this with SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In terms of storing in SQL looking at the data, what do you suggest the schema should be

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help guys I will store in database as 3 columns 2 columns will be used to store the ticker pairs with the third column storing the correlation value

Answer (score -1):

DataTables with lazy loading could be a good option to render large sized tables as HTML and backend pagination will a be a good way to manage resources and bandwidth